How to pass two curly braces as json value (not a string) for a json object in java?
I currently have a graphQL endpoint that has a request body with two json objects, variables and query.  The request body should look like below:
{
    "variables": {},
    "query": "{\n  uploadQueueSummary {\n    fileName\n    createdBy\n    salesId\n    completedRows\n    totalRows\n    uploadUUID\n    uploadTime\n    status\n    hasErrors\n    uploadType\n    demandType\n    errorRows\n    deletedRows\n    failedRows\n  }\n}"
}

When I use the below code, the variables object value is coming as a String instead, regardless if hard-coded or get from POJO:
GraphQLQuery queryAndVars = new GraphQLQuery() //POJO class
JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject;
requestBody.put("query",queryAndVars.getQuery());
requestBody.put("variables", "{}");

The request body is as below after I run my code:
{
    "variables": "{}",
    "query": "{\n  uploadQueueSummary {\n    fileName\n    createdBy\n    salesId\n    completedRows\n    totalRows\n    uploadUUID\n    uploadTime\n    status\n    hasErrors\n    uploadType\n    demandType\n    errorRows\n    deletedRows\n    failedRows\n  }\n}"
}

How can I set the JSONObject key (variables) value without treating it as a String?

Have you tried setting varaibles to null?

The code you have posted is not syntactically valid Java. Please post runnable code that reproduces the problem when run.

By setting it to "{}" yourself, you are literally saying "I want the content to be a string, and that string is the two letters { and }". If you want it to be an empty object once serialized to JSON, you need to actually assign it an object, not a string.

You should try this
GraphQLQuery queryAndVars = new GraphQLQuery() //POJO class
JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();
requestBody.put("query",queryAndVars.getQuery());
requestBody.put("variables", new JSONObject());

in Json {} is the representation of an object.

Rather than string {} , pass it as new JSONObject()
Replace your line :
requestBody.put("variables", "{}");

with this :
requestBody.put("variables", new JSONObject());


I think instead of using "{}" string, you can simply replace it with new Object() or new JSONObject() as follows:
requestBody.put("variables", new Object());

OR
requestBody.put("variables", new JSONObject());

